# Linux / Windows: Dual boot Installation on RAID0

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, raid, uefi

I need to install a Linux distribution on my laptop (an Asus UX302LA) but I couldn't even begin the installation.

To explain you my problem, I know that Windows is installed in UEFI mode. Furthermore, I have discovered that I have a RAID0, probably a software one, in my laptop.

I tried to install the latest version of Ubuntu and Mint, both 64bits. I find some tutorials on the internet but I'm so afraid about deleting all my data (and also the recovery partition).

*How do I install a dual boot on a RAID0?*

Comment: First of all, you could give a bit more information about the system you're trying to install on (manufacturer, model, kind of disk controller, …).

Comment: Maybe you want to disable EFI mode in BIOS before beginning installation?

Comment: Hi guys, my laptop is an Asus UX302LA with an HDD of 256 GB. I thought there was only one HDD but I discovered that there is a raid0. I know also that Windows 8 is installed in UEFI mode. I don't know if you need more information ;) I tried already to install by disabling UEFI mode but I got an error directly after the begining of the installation :-\

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do it is the short answer:**  RAID0 is worse than no RAID at all from a reliability perspective.

**Long answer what you should do:**

- Take a [CloneZilla Live backup](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) of the pre-installed Windows environment on the RAID-0.
- Download [RTSCLI64 V 13.2.0_1016](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24310/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-Command-Line-Interface-CLI) and then [patch it](https://communities.intel.com/message/414989#414989) to ignore driver version checking.
- Boot Windows into command prompt mode using the recovery environment and delete the RAID array with the patched RSTCLI64:

  ```
  rstcli64 --manage --delete OEMRAID0
  ```
- [Edit the CloneZilla Image to allow restoring on a smaller disk](https://serverfault.com/questions/568227/prepare-a-disk-to-be-imaged-by-clonezilla-for-use-on-smaller-disks)
- Restore the CloneZilla Image to the first drive of the split RAID0
- Install your distro of choice on the second drive of the split RAID0 normally